# Display mulicolumn in dropdown list control at a time

Tags: asp.net

Is there any way that i can display 2 columns value horizontally partitioned in dropdown list control at a time.

Comment: The only way to do this would be to Concatenate two columns in your SQL itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not out-of-the-box. There are some third party controls such as [Telerik ComboBox](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multicolumncombo/defaultcs.aspx) which allow you to achieve this functionality.